# understanding this Python script

Tags: python, python-3.x

I got this code and i'm trying to figure out how this works

```
class Animal(object):
    population = 0
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __str__(self):
        return "I am an instance of {}. ".format(self.__class__, self.name)
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.__str__()

    def make_sound(self):
        return "{} is trying to speak, but its method doesn't do much".format(self.name)

class Dog(Animal):
    def __init__(self, name, breed):
        super().__init__(name)
        self.breed = breed
    def __str__(self):
        print(super().__str__())
        return "My breed is {}".format(self.breed)

    def make_sound(self):
        return "{} says woof!".format(self.name)

class Cat(Animal):
    pass


animals = {'Felix': ('Cat', None), 'Fido': ('Dog', 'mutt'), 'Charlie': ('Dog', 'spaniel')}
animals_list = []
for k in animals:
    if animals[k][1]:
        animals_list.append(globals()[animals[k][0]](k, animals[k][1]))
    else:
        animals_list.append(globals()[animals[k][0]](k))
    Animal.population+=1

for animal in animals_list:
    print(animal)
    print(animal.make_sound())
print("Animal population is {}".format(Animal.population))
```

How are the classes initiated? I can't get my head around how this is done, seems the classes dog and cat are already initiated when the script reaches the if animals part.

Thanks in advance

Comment: That is some ugly code.  There was absolutely no reason to use the animal type as a string like `'Cat'` and then look it up in `globals()`, when you can just use the name `Cat` instead.

Comment: What is it you don't understand? Have in mind that the part that begins with the animal dictionary assigning is the first to run

Comment: `animals[k][0]` is the name of the class, `globals()['Cat']` returns the `Cat` class,, the rest are constructor parameters.

Comment: +1. Perfectly cromulent programming question with a clear ask and a reasonable position for confusion. Downvoters: j'accuse!

Comment: @kojiro quelle est la signification du mot 'cromulent' ?

Comment: @joaquin C'est un [néologisme anglais](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cromulent) humoristique de "The Simpsons".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The classes are instantiated inside this for loop:

```
for k in animals:
    if animals[k][1]:
        animals_list.append(globals()[animals[k][0]](k, animals[k][1]))  # Instantiates a class
    else:
        animals_list.append(globals()[animals[k][0]](k))  # Instantiates a class
```

So, if `k` is `'Felix'`, this code is saying:

```
if None: # Because animals['Felix'][1] is None
    animals_list.append(globals()['Cat']('Felix', None))
else:
    animals_list.append(globals()['Cat']('Felix'))
```

[`globals()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#globals) returns a dictionary containing the name -> object mapping of all variables in the global namespace. So, `globals()['Cat']` returns the actual `Cat` class. That means `globals()['Cat']('Felix')` is equivalent to `Cat('Felix')`. And that, obviously, is instantiating the `Cat` class with the name `'Felix'`. This same pattern repeats for every entry in the `animals` dict, so in the end, the `animals_list` contains the instances returned by calling `Cat('Felix')`, `Dog('Fido', 'mutt')`, and `Dog('Charlie', 'spaniel')`.

And for what its worth, I agree with the commentors who have pointed out this code is quite ugly. It makes much more sense to do this:

```
animals = {'Felix': (Cat, None), 'Fido': (Dog, 'mutt'), 'Charlie': (Dog, 'spaniel')}
animals_list = []
for k in animals:
    if animals[k][1]:
        animals_list.append(animals[k][0](k, animals[k][1]))
    else:
        animals_list.append(animals[k][0](k))
```

No need to use `globals()`.